# Redirect to two ports using Nginx

Tags: nginx

I have two angular apps running on different ports. I need to access app1 when the user calls https://url and app2 when the user calls https://url/admin. I tried adding location block to the Nginx config as below but the request is directed to app1 with the /admin added.

```
server {
#        listen 80 default_server;
#        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        listen 443 ssl;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;

        server_name fr.techolution.com;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/url_com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/myserver.key;
location / {
 proxy_pass http://192.168.2.81:8083;
}
location  /admin {
 proxy_pass http://192.168.2.81:4200;
}
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that "location /admin/" matches https ://url/admin (notice the trailing "/".

Comment: Are you sure the second app is listening on IP 192.168.2.81?    Anything in nginx' error log?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
location  /admin {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.2.81:4200;
}
```

Comment: I tried it but didn't work out. The request is still directed to the 8083 app

Comment: Make sure your browser cache isn't fooling you.